# Where can I store my IOS Certificate files (.p12)?

Tags: ios, certificate, storage

I would like to know where can I store my IOS certificates and keys.

Every time I switch to an old project which has been developed by another programmer to make a fix and deploy it, I spend a lot of time trying to find which certificate and provisioning file is the appropriate. I can find these certificates in the developer account but they do not include the key that I need to install it on my computer. Sometimes these certificates are created by the client, and the task is even more tedious because I have to request it.

What I'm looking for is a tool to store exported certificates with keys so I can share it with other programmers, and also a place where I can look for certificates created by other programmers. I was thinking on storing them on a private git repository but I'm not sure if that's a good solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you create certificates just double click on it, it will get automatically saved in Keychain. You don't need to select each time while building app.

Answer (score 3):

Think you should take a look at [fastlane match](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/). Underneath it is using git to store certs and provision profiles, it is secure as each file will be encrypted using openssl via a passphrase.

Match will install certificates and private keys in your Keychain.

[Here](https://github.com/fastlane/examples/tree/master/Acast) you can take a look on a sample implementation of match

Comment: Thanks Evghaenni! This is the kind of answer I was looking for. I'll take a loot to fastlane match.

Answer (score 2):

The Keychain application that's included with every copy of MacOS X is a good place to store private keys and certificates, especially since Xcode will look for them there.

If you have a number of projects from different clients, you can store the certificates and keys for each client in a separate keychain. That'll help keep them organized and help avoid using the wrong credentials for a given project.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to edit my question, as what I'm looking for it's to share certificates with other programmers easily without having to export what's installed in the KeyChain, and vice-versa.